# @ExceptionHandler in Spring

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

In my application I have configured an error page in web.xml. I need to override that for a specific controller based on a condition. Here when a condition becomes true I need to redirect to a specific error page otherwise normal error page should be rendered.
Here is the code. Please help me.

```
@Controller
public class Test{

 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public ModelAndView generateException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
  if(condition) {
   return new ModelAndView("myError.jsp");
  } else {
   //should execute default error page.
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw the exception again which will be handled by DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver to respond with the error page defined in your web.xml; It doesn't invoke the same Exception Handler of the controller.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView generateException(Exception ex) throws Exception{
    if(condition) {
        return new ModelAndView("myError.jsp");
    } else {
        //should execute default error page.
        throw ex;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks vinay. This is perfect.

Comment: If you are satisfied, would you mind accept it as the answer please? ;)